# Migrate useRouterHistory

Tags: react-router, migration, history.js

I am migrating and app with pretty old react-router (2.8.0) to v6. I couldn't find out how to migrate this line.

```
const ReactRouter = require( 'react-router' ),
    createHashHistory = require( 'react-outer/node_modules/history/lib/createHashHistory' ),
    createHashHistory = require( 'react-router/node_modules/history' ).createHashHistory,
    useRouterHistory = ReactRouter.useRouterHistory;

var appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)( { queryKey: false } );
```

I found out that the location for `createHashHistory` changed to `require( 'react-router/node_modules/history' ).createHashHistory`, but I couldn't find out what to do with `useRouterHistory`.

If I omit it I no longer have `query` in the object causing a lot of dependent code to break.

I read through this [issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/2814), but all the links there are broken:(

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you followed ***any*** of the migration guides (*v2 to v3, v3 to v4/v5, v5 to v6*)? `react-router-dom` v6 has some pretty non-trivial breaking changes, one of them being abstracting/internalizing the `history` object and not exposing it out. You'd need to create a custom router to still use a custom history object. I have no idea what `useRouterHistory` is from such an old version (which seems to predate React hooks). What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese !

I checked this guide - https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-to-react-router-v51 . But from your answer, it sounds like there should be more? Could you link me to those, please?

For the context, this is a legacy app (arent they all?:)) that somebody else wrote. I am not sure what the end goal was there. But it did provide that `query` attribute to history, which is missing if I don't use it.

I also tried to google for it first as described above.

Any suggestions on what else to try?

Comment: Yeah, you kind of have to go digging for them. Here's the v5 [README](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/v5) that references back to v2/3. v4 was a complete rewrite, and v6 is close to a rewrite. TBH I'm not sure how much effort it'd be to take a migration pitstop at v4/5, but maybe there's a clear migration path. It may just be easier to dissect the "legacy" project to understand what it's doing, and rewrite just the incompatible sections.

Comment: From what I can tell, `useRouterHistory` is a higher order function decorating a history object. I'm guessing you can just import `createHashHistory` and use it, i.e. `const history = createHashHistory();`.... or just use the v6 `HashRouter` which does this internally for you. The only reason to use the low-level `Router` component is if you need a custom history object to use an code ***outside*** React, i.e. like Redux thunks, etc...